# Angular 16 Resolvers - How to handle redirection to child

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular16, angular-resolver

I'm just really looking for some general advice on best practice here as it's the first time I've had to use resolvers.

So the current flow of my application...

- App initialisation function to check auth and either authenticate user or not if they still have auth token
- resolver on the root '' path that basically does a whole bunch of set up for the route the user goes to after logging in. This resolver finally redirects to a child route.
- resolver on child route to do some final configuration setup

Now I just want to check if this structure is right or wrong?

Sone of the problems I can think of is...

1. It could result in an infinite loop as I'm navigating to a child from the parent resolver
2. From what I understand its bad practice to do route navigation in a resolver and resolver should be purely for data setup
3. The routing from the parent resolver oddly doesn't seem to change the url. I'm assuming this is a side effect of redirecting in a resolver?

So what would be the correct flow for me to use here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're right the resolver shouldn't fire navigation.

Navigation should be fired by guards like `canActivate` !

Comment: So in my scenario what guards should I create? And on what routes should the guards sit? The part that's confusing me is surely the guard would have to set on the root path in my scenario but then I always want the root path active.

Comment: I guess on the root path I could check if the user is authenticated and then redirect if so. But I also need to make sure that the resolver on the root path has happened before the guard redirects.

Comment: And now from what I read the guard fires before the resolver. So not sure how this would work.